# About HTML and CSS ancestor-descendant relation

Tags: html, css

Given the HTML snippet:

```
<div class="class"></div>
```

What's the difference (& consequence) between the styling (CSS):

1. `div.class`
2. `div .class`

N/B: There is white space between div and .class in (2), but not in (1).

Answer (score 0):

The first example selects all divs with the class "class".

The second example selects all descendant elements of a div that have the class "class".

So your example HTML would only be selected by example 1 (unless the HTML was a child of a div, in which case example 2 would also select it).

Answer (score -2):

You should do research before asking questions on SO. You could have found the answer you were looking for with one Google search, here is the answer:

`div.class`:  Selects all `div` elements with `class="class"`

`div .class`: Selects all elements with class that is a descendant of an element with `div`

Taken directly from [W3 Schools CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: _"Selects all elements with both div and class set within its class attribute"_ Incorrect

Comment: W3 schools..., nevertheless, I do believe they should have googled it for a minute, or half a minute to find the solution.